# Can it be necessary to require a module (child_process in this case) more than once?

Tags: node.js

In a code I picked up, the `app.js` contains, in the same scope:

```
var childProcess1 = require("child_process");
childProcess1.fork(...)
...
var childProcess2 = require("child_process");
childProcess2.fork(...)
```

Can there be any reason to require twice?

PS: more details on request :)

Comment: Are they in different functions?

Comment: edited, yes they are.

Comment: Well, it's just visibility scope issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will virtually never be necessary. In fact, the [values returned by `require` are cached](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/200652/51295), so the first call to `require("foo")` actually runs the module, while additional calls simply access the original return value stored in `require.cache` (in particular, `require.cache[require.resolve("foo")]`).

The only case multiple calls would be necessary (or have any effect whatsoever) is if your code tampers with `require.cache`, which it probably shouldn't do.

Answer (score 2):

It could be necessary, if `require`s are in different functions. Like this:

```
function foo() {
  var childProcess1 = require("child_process");
  childProcess1.fork(...)
}

function bar() {
  // here you can't use childProcess1, so
  var childProcess2 = require("child_process");
  childProcess2.fork(...)
}
```

But it's better to change the code to something like this:

```
var childProcess = require("child_process");

function foo() {
  childProcess.fork(...)
}

function bar() {
  childProcess.fork(...)
}
```

There could be reason not to have global variable like this (but not with built-in `child_process` module I guess)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you just `require()` a module once, since future `require()`s for the same module will return the exact same value. Because of this trait, re-using the result of the first `require()` avoids the additional, minimal overhead of a call to `require()`.